# organize php and html in symfony framework

Tags: javascript, php

I have already finished a project in php (using php, html, java script, SQL) and then I realized that it's supposed that I organize it in symfony's framework, can I put it in the framework directly ? or I'll need to start from the beginning ? (I'm new to symfony)
thanks a lot

Comment: You can probably reuse some of your code, but you'll need to rewrite a bunch to be Synfony'ic